# SQL Stored Procedure if statement with bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this if condition in my SQL Stored Procedure:

```
@isAlphabeticalSort bit = false

    if(@isAlphabeticalSort = false)
        ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
    Else
        ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
```

but I get a few errors with this:

> Invalid Column name false
>
> Incorrect Syntax near 'ORDER'

I even tried adding the begin and end in between the if and the else and still I get the same errors....what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
@isAlphabeticalSort bit = 0
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

You might also look at how your ORDER BY is written...

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE @isAlphabeticalSort 
      WHEN 0 THEN V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END 
      ELSE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER 
   END
```

Edit:
You need to handle the conversion error(s) -- ex.:

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE @isAlphabeticalSort 
      WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END,112) 
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER)
   END
```

Comment: this works when isAlphabeticalSort is 0, but when I get it to 1 I get this error when I run the stored procedure: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Answer (score 2):

`TSQL` recognizes [bits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) as either `1` or `0`.

So you can do:

```
@isAlphabeticalSort bit = 0

if(@isAlphabeticalSort = 0)
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
Else
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
```

OR

```
@isAlphabeticalSort bit = 0

if(@isAlphabeticalSort = CAST('FALSE' AS BIT))
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
Else
    ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
```

to check the bit value.

Edit:

All three of these statements are equivalent:

- `if(@isAlphabeticalSort = 0)`
- `if(@isAlphabeticalSort = CAST('false' as bit))`
- `if(@isAlphabeticalSort = CONVERT(bit, 'false'))`